# KotlinNullPointerException: inside onCreateOptionsMenu can't find searchView; android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, kotlin, searchview

I need MainActivity with SearchView, it throws KotlinNullPointerException: inside onCreateOptionsMenu; here is my code:

options_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/search" />
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.Menu
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.SearchView
import android.widget.Toast
...
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.app.SearchManager
import android.content.Context


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    logd("onCreate MainActivity")
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    ...
} 
...
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
    val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
    val searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.search).actionView as? SearchView
    searchView!!.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
    return true
}
```

i am using custom toolbar like this but i think problem is not here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No value passed for parameter item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309872/no-value-passed-for-parameter-item)

Comment: Please, provide full stack trace.

Comment: You have the same problem as this question, you have different `SearchView` classes in your XML and in your Kotlin file. Just make sure you use the one from the support library everywhere.

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov can't put all code stackoverflow swears

Comment: @zsmb13  
i have checked it both of them i have android.widget.SearchView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` to `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` it will work fine.

Comment: i dont understand why android does not work but app work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in app:actionViewClass

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/itemSearch"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
```

you must make actionViewClass is same in Activity

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
```

The MainActivity is extends from AppCompatActivity
also the AppCompatActivity is import like that

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

I hope support everyone here

Best Regards